# unresolved external symbol on unitest file (visual studio)

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I'm doing my first test with c++ and visual studio and I don't know why, I have a problem of " unresolved external symbol " when it doesn't happen in the program.

> Error 97  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static
>   class Session * __cdecl Session::Instance(void)"
>   (?Instance@Session@@SAPAV1@XZ)    (...)\MyTest\Messages.obj   MyTest
>
> Error 98  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: char *
>   __thiscall Config::getLanguage(void)" (?getLanguage@Config@@QAEPADXZ) (...)\MyTest\Messages.obj   MyTest
>
> Error 99  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class wxString
>   StringTranslate"
>   (?StringTranslate@@3VwxString@@A) (...)\MyTest\Messages.obj   MyTest
>
> Error 100 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: void
>   __thiscall Session::addMSG(class std::shared_ptr)" (?addMSG@Session@@QAEXV?$shared_ptr@VMessage@@@std@@@Z)(...)\speech-translation-tools\MyTest\Messages.obj   MyTest
>
> Error 101 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: char *
>   __thiscall Config::getNick(void)" (?getNick@Config@@QAEPADXZ) (...)speech-translation-tools\MyTest\Messages.obj   MyTest
>
> Error 102 error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: char *
>   __thiscall Config::getServerAddress(void)" (?getServerAddress@Config@@QAEPADXZ)   (...) MyTest\Messages.obj   MyTest
>   Error 103 error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals

test file:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "CppUnitTest.h" 
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/stattext.h> 
#include "data/Session.h"

#include "lib/ClientTS.cpp"
using namespace Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework;

namespace MessageTXT    
{
    TEST_CLASS(UnitTest1)
    {

    public:
        TEST_METHOD(TEST_MESSAGE_SEND)
        {
            ClientTS *clientts = new ClientTS;
            wxString sr = "enviar_mensaje";
            clientts->sendMessage(&sr);
            clientts->disconnect();

        }
    };
}
```

Clientts.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __BORLANDC__
#pragma hdrstop
#endif

#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/frame.h>
#else
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#endif

#include "../data/Session.h"
#include "../data/Message.h"
#include "../data/Config.h"

#include "EventType.h" 

#include <wx/sizer.h>
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/timer.h>
#include <wx/stattext.h>
#include <wx/richtext/richtextctrl.h>
#include <wx/textctrl.h>
#include <wx/button.h>
#include <wx/grid.h>
#include "../gui/NationList.h"
#include "../gui/NationInfo.h" 
#include "../ArchiveLog.h"

#include "../GlobalVariables.h"
#include "../translateController/translateController.h"
#include "../translateController/translateVariable.h"

#include <list>
#include <functional> 

#define MENU_ESCI 1800
#define MENU_OPZIONI 1801
#define MENU_SPEECH 1802


typedef std::function<void()> cbClientTsFrm;


class ClientTS  {
public:
    static Session* session;
    static ConfigPTR config;
    static bool flagSave;
    static char LANG_MSG_SRC[500];
    static char MSG_SRC[500];
    static cbClientTsFrm notifyMSGcb;
    //static ISoundEngine* engine;              //Audio Engine to record sound
    static IAudioRecorder* recorder;            //Flow of audio daa
    //static uint64 scHandlerID;

    static char identity[IDENTITY_BUFSIZE];

    /* Create struct for callback function pointers */
    static struct ClientUIFunctions funcs;
public:
    ClientTS(){
        session = Session::Instance();
        config = session->getConfig();
    }

    virtual ~ClientTS(){}

    static void sendMessage(wxString *msgToSend);

    static void disconnect();
    static char* getLANG_MSG_SRC(){ return LANG_MSG_SRC; }

    static char* getMSG_SRC(){ return MSG_SRC; }
    static IAudioRecorder* getIAudioRecorder(){ return recorder; }

    static bool getFlagSave(){ return flagSave; }

    static void setFlagSave(bool flg){ flagSave = flg; }
    template <typename Observer>
    static void setCBClientTSMSG(Observer && fn){ notifyMSGcb = std::forward<Observer>(fn); }

    static void speak(char *LANG, char*MSG);
    static void Print(char*word);
    static size_t read_callback(static void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, static void *userp);
    static void writeWaveFile(const char* filename, SAudioStreamFormat format, static void* data);
    static void SetupColor(COLORE *c);
    static void onConnectStatusChangeEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, int newStatus, unsigned int errorNumber);
    static void onNewChannelEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, uint64 channelID, uint64 channelParentID);
    static void onNewChannelCreatedEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, uint64 channelID, uint64 channelParentID, anyID invokerID, const char* invokerName, const char* invokerUniqueIdentifier);
    static void onDelChannelEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, uint64 channelID, anyID invokerID, const char* invokerName, const char* invokerUniqueIdentifier);
    static void onClientMoveEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, anyID clientID, uint64 oldChannelID, uint64 newChannelID, int visibility, const char* moveMessage);
    static void onClientMoveSubscriptionEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, anyID clientID, uint64 oldChannelID, uint64 newChannelID, int visibility);
    static void onClientMoveTimeoutEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, anyID clientID, uint64 oldChannelID, uint64 newChannelID, int visibility, const char* timeoutMessage);
    static void onTalkStatusChangeEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, int status, int isReceivedWhisper, anyID clientID);
    static void onIgnoredWhisperEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, anyID clientID);
    static void onServerErrorEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, const char* errorMessage, unsigned int error, const char* returnCode, const char* extraMessage);
    static void onUserLoggingMessageEvent(const char* logMessage, int logLevel, const char* logChannel, uint64 logID, const char* logTime, const char* completeLogString);
    static void onCustomPacketEncryptEvent(char** dataToSend, unsigned int* sizeOfData);
    static void onCustomPacketDecryptEvent(char** dataReceived, unsigned int* dataReceivedSize);
    static void onEditMixedPlaybackVoiceDataEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, short* samples, int sampleCount, int channels, const unsigned int* channelSpeakerArray, unsigned int* channelFillMask);
    static void showChannels(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID);
    static void showChannelClients(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, uint64 channelID);
    static void onTextMessageEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, anyID targetMode, anyID toID, anyID fromID, const char* fromName, const char* fromUniqueIdentifier, const char* message);
    static void showClients(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID);
    static void createChannel(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, const char *name);
    static void deleteChannel(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID);
    static void renameChannel(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID);
    static void switchChannel(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID);
    static void toggleVAD(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID);
    static void setVadLevel(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID);
    static void requestWhisperList(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID);
    static void requestClearWhisperList(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID);
    static void toggleRecordSound(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID);
    static int readIdentity(char* identity);
    static int writeIdentity(const char* identity);
    static uint64  enterChannelID();
    static void createDefaultChannelName(char *name);
    static void enterName(char *name); 
    static void emptyInputBuffer();

    static DWORD WINAPI TTS_THREAD(LPVOID lpParameter);
    static DWORD WINAPI CTRL_STT(LPVOID lpParameter);
    static DWORD WINAPI ClientStart(LPVOID lpParameter);
    static DWORD WINAPI STT_THREAD(LPVOID lpParameter);
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You are including a .cpp file

```
#include "lib/ClientTS.cpp"
```

should it be?

```
#include "lib/ClientTS.h"
```

Comment: Excellently pointed out !  However, if all the project dependencies were included,  this would have triggered either compilation errors (missing definitions of the .h) or LNK1169 / LNK2005 error messages (i.e. multiply defined symbols)

Answer (score 1):

The message points out *unresolved external symbols*.

This means that you code is syntactically correct but not all the external symbols you refer to (class `Session` and class `Config` member functions) are found when linking all the .obj and .lib files together.

This means that you have missing dependencies:  either source files missing in the project, or 'more probably) a library file.

Comment: Thanks @christophe! And do you have any idea on how to solve this? Perhaps.. it's possible that my control class is programmed on the wrong way, any suggestion? Thank you very much!

Comment: Sure: can you provide a list of all the cpp that are in the project that you compile ? Can you also tell in which one you have defined the two above mentionned classes ?

Comment: maybe it's easier if I put her the repository to see the list. Thanks again for your time.

https://github.com/danieltoledo/speech-translation-tools/tree/teamspeak/client/src

Comment: It's easier, but doesn't completely answer the need.  I can find both `Config` and `Session` in the `data` folder.  I imagine that you've compiled these modules as part of your library or application.  But didn't you create a separate project for your unit tests ?  Have you included either the relevant source files in the test project ?  Or alternatively did you include the .lib/.dll/.obj file as external dependency to your project ?  If not sure,  could you add the .sln and .vcxproj files in your github repository ?

Comment: Yes, I did a separate project for my tests! And I think I added the source files because there's no error with clientts.cpp class, for example. Just with the classes linked. You can find the whole project in the previous folder, this:

https://github.com/danieltoledo/speech-translation-tools/tree/teamspeak/client

Comment: The fact that you don't get an error at compilation but at linking, suggests that you have insert all required declarations (so compiler is aware of Session & Config) but not the definitions (i;e. the corresponding cpp).  Your error message refers to a folder MyTest with a Message.cpp.  I couldn't find this on your github.  Furhtermore the only project file on the your repoistory doesn't include any message at all.  Last but not least, after a while, I found a MyTest.dll.  I analysed it with dumpbin, and it's unrelated to you error message. It's difficult to help with only part of the info :-/

Comment: Yep sorry @Christophe, I discarded the commit with Message.cpp. However, you can find it on my question above. Thank you for your time.